# Stop UITableView section headers from moving on scroll

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have the following code:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    let header: UITableViewHeaderFooterView = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.frame.insetInPlace(dx: 55, dy: 0)
}
```

I am moving view over 55 so that it won't be overlapped by the center view as this view is a right side panel. As soon as I scroll the table view in that side panel, the position seems to revert, making my labels disappear under the center view. If I collapse the side menu and reopen it, the position is reset. I want the view to stay at 55. What should I do?

Comment: I think adding custom cells to your header rows will give a solution to this issue. And then add logic in cellForRowAtIndexPath to get the right cell back when it comes to header

Comment: check the heightForHeaderInSection returning always same value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to just move the section header position I decided to move the entire child view controller over. That way I don't need to manipulate the position of all the section headers and cell labels/icons. It was just a lot easier for me all around.

So as an answer, consider moving the underlying view.